# Cosmology, MOND and TeVeS

Tags: cosmology, modified-gravity

I have read the Wiki page about [TeVeS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor%E2%80%93vector%E2%80%93scalar_gravity). It says that MOND (or rather, AQUAL) is its nonrelativistic limit.

I wrote a thesis on cosmology eons ago (no, seriously, more than 50 years ago!) and though I learned some GR at the time, I cannot say I follow the details of the Lagrangian of TeVeS.

So I have just two simple questions. I'll accept a convincing answer on any of the two, and if necessary ask another question on the second one.

One : Assuming the mass distribution is homogeneous on a large enough scale, as it appears to be (that is, we are not in a fractal Universe, nor in a special region),
would TeVes give the same result around any origin ? I mean, are the predictions of Teves, computed with a Lagragian centered on us, for some region extremely far from us, coincide, once the appropriate correction for the expansion are made, with the predictions around us ? In other words, does TeVeS preserve homogeneity ?

Two: Is there a room in TeVeS for something like the "dark energy" or a Cosmological Constant ("Lambda") ? Can it explain an asymptotically exponential future expansion ? I did not see it in the Lagrangian, but as I said, I cannot really follow the details.
However if MOND is the nonrelativistic limit of TeVeS then the acceleration parameter a_0 of MOND must somehow appear in the parameters of TeVeS. And one thing I do know is that the square of a_0/c^2 is of the same **order of magnitude** as the best estimates for the Cosmological Constant ("Lambda"; or equivalently, the "dark energy" in the proper units, expressed as inverse squared meters) in the more standard versions. Personally, I don't see any connection (MOND increases the attraction of gravity while Lambda is repulsive, so they are antagonists) but it is a curious coincidence. Any comment on that coincidence would be welcome.